# Is there a way to iterate through objects with similar names in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have some code that works perfectly, but it seems like there's a more elegant way to do the same thing. Here's the code:

```
SeekBar burpeeSelector1;
SeekBar burpeeSelector2;
SeekBar burpeeSelector3;
SeekBar burpeeSelector4;
SeekBar burpeeSelector5;

Boolean burpeeSwitch1Status = true;
Boolean burpeeSwitch2Status = true;
Boolean burpeeSwitch3Status = true;
Boolean burpeeSwitch4Status = true;
Boolean burpeeSwitch5Status = true;

public void updateTotals(){

    int pushupValue1 = 0;
    int pushupValue2 = 0;
    int pushupValue3 = 0;
    int pushupValue4 = 0;
    int pushupValue5 = 0;
    
    if(burpeeSwitch1Status){
        pushupValue1 = burpeeSelector1.getProgress();
    } else{
        burpeeTotal-=setsSeekBar.getProgress()*burpeePrimer1.getProgress();
    }

    if(burpeeSwitch2Status){
        pushupValue2 = burpeeSelector2.getProgress();
    } else{
        burpeeTotal-=setsSeekBar.getProgress()*burpeePrimer2.getProgress();
    }

    if(burpeeSwitch3Status){
        pushupValue3 = burpeeSelector3.getProgress();
    } else{
        burpeeTotal-=setsSeekBar.getProgress()*burpeePrimer3.getProgress();
    }

    if(burpeeSwitch4Status){
        pushupValue4 = burpeeSelector4.getProgress();
    } else{
        burpeeTotal-=setsSeekBar.getProgress()*burpeePrimer4.getProgress();
    }

    if(burpeeSwitch5Status){
        pushupValue5 = burpeeSelector5.getProgress();
    } else{
        burpeeTotal-=setsSeekBar.getProgress()*burpeePrimer5.getProgress();
    }
    
    //...
    
}
```

How would you make this more elegant?

My idea to simplify the code is to replace the booleans with an array and replace the ints with an array, then use a for loop to run the algorithm that gets repeated on each boolean. However, though each chunk of code does the same thing, each chunk also references different objects (burpeeSelector1, burpeeSelector2, etc.) Is there some syntax trick that will allow me to abstract this out so I can use my for loop idea?

Comment: Using an array is the correct idea.  You can't do anything based on variable names; all you can do is use the array for everything: instead of `burpeeSelector1`, write `burpeeSelector[0]` everywhere.  You just need to initialize the array appropriately.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Are you looking for arrays?

Answer (score 1):

you can create class :

```
class burpeeSelector{
   public boolean status;
   public int value;
   public SeekBar seekBar;

   burpeeSelector(int value,boolean status,SeekBar seekBar){
      this.status = status;
      this.value= value;
      this.seekBar= seekBar;
   }
}
```

then create ArrayList and initialize it like this;

```
ArrayList<burpeeSelector> burpeeSelectorList = new ArrayList<>(); 
burpeeSelectorList.add(new burpeeSelector(0,true,burpeeSelector1));
burpeeSelectorList.add(new burpeeSelector(0,true,burpeeSelector2));
.
.
.
```

then use forLoop to access to values